# No Module named XXX after I add python 3 kernel in Anaconda jupyter

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, anaconda, jupyter

Today, I want to add Python-3 in my jupyter notebook, using code like this:

```
  conda create -n py3k python=3 anaconda   
  source activate py3k
```

After that, I try to import some module in python-2 kernel, but it shows like:

http://i5.tietuku.com/5b100b873045c3b2.png

I already install pandas in :

http://i5.tietuku.com/ffe771f50084b875.png

My python was installed in:

http://i5.tietuku.com/f701abf225a2823d.png

I think the problem is my jupyter environment can't link with my module that I already installed.

But I don't know how to fix that.

I want to set the env like **/User/HYF/Anaconda/bin**

But when I use sys.executable, it shows like **/User/HYF/Anacnoda/env/bin/py27**

Wish for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my error.
After I read this doc:
[Change in behavior launching ipython notebooks from anacona environment](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/541)

I found out the Anaconda environment has changed for the jupyter notebook.

Every module was fine when I use ipython qtconsole.

So I reinstall the ipython notebook, and the problem had been fixed.

```
 python -m IPython kernelspec install-self
```

Comment: Sorry for my error.
After I read this doc:     
[Change in behavior launching ipython notebooks from anacona environment](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/541)    

I found out the Anaconda environment has changed for the jupyter notebook.     

Every module was fine when I use ipython qtconsole.    

So I reinstall the ipython notebook, and the problem had been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the tip is to install modules under py3 environment,
so activate py3 before you install them.

This is what I do in Windows7:

```
activate ipykernel_py3
conda intall pandas
```